# Layer state outlines on top of a map plot

Tags: r, dictionary, plot, shapefile

I have used shapefiles to create map files in R based on certain criteria. The code is shown below

```
   library('sp')
library('rgdal')
library('maptools')
gpclibPermit()
zip<-readShapePoly("C:/Users/Ishan.Basu/Desktop/shapefile/shapefile ZIP/USZ102.shp")
plot(zip)
ms2<-read.table("C:/Users/Ishan.Basu/Desktop/MS.txt",header=T,sep="\t",colClasses="character",as.is=T)

zip@data = merge(zip@data,ms2, by.x="ZIP", by.y="ZIP")

x<-zip@data
plot(zip,col=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performers",'Dark Green',
                      ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performers",'Light Green',
                    ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performers",'Yellow',
                           ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero Returns",'Red',
                                  ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero Activity",'Dark Red',
                                         'Grey'))))),
     border=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performers",'Dark Green',
                   ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performers",'Light Green',
                          ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performers",'Yellow',
                                 ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero Returns",'Red',
                                        ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero Activity",'Dark Red',
                                               'Grey'))))),
     bty="n")
```

Now I want a way by which I can plot state outlines on top of the shape files.
Quick reply will be much appreciated

Comment: It is recommended to use `readOGR` instead of `readShapePoly` to open shape file.

Comment: I have everything working out but I need to add the state outlines on top

Comment: What is the projection of your shapefile?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
png(filename="D:\\analysis_f.png", width=2000, height=2000)
plot(zip,col=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Super Top",'Dark Green',
                      ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performer",'Light Green',
                    ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performer",'Yellow',
                           ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performer",'Red',
                                  ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero returns",'Dark Red',
                                         'Grey'))))),
     border=ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Super Top",'Dark Green',
                   ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Top Performer",'Light Green',
                          ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Average Performer",'Yellow',
                                 ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Poor Performer",'Red',
                                        ifelse(zip@data$Seg=="Zero returns",'Dark Red',
                                               'Grey'))))),
     bty="n")

map('state', plot = TRUE, fill = FALSE,add=TRUE)
dev.off()
```